# I want to assign one variable twice but only want to use first one in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

There is a file name vicidial.php in vicidia file a value is assigned

```
var DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'something'
```

I dont want to edit in this file but i want to edit this variable from other file so i created file_js.js but when i assigned var DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'my_value' its only use first one eg. something i want to override my variable. how can i do this ?

```
  <script src="file_js.js"></script>
  in vicidial.php
  var DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'default value';


  in file_js.js
  var DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'my_value';
```

Comment: don't redeclare DiaLControl_auto_HTML variable with var prefix. Use it directly : DiaLControl_auto_HTML="what you want" (without "var" in front of the instruction ). But warning  : this instruction must be executed after yout main script where you have var  DiaLControl_auto_HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In vicidial have:

```
<script>
var DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'default value';
</script>
 <script src="file_js.js"></script>
```

in file_js.js

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  window.DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'my_value';
})
```

Comment: thanks for response not working @mplungjan
i dont know if i m doing something wrong

Comment: Impossible to say with the code you have shown so far. 
If the var in the PHP `var DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'something' ` is not outside some function, then you cannot replace it

Comment: in js_file.js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  window.DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'my_value';
})




in vicidial.php
<script src='js_file.js'></script>
<script>
       var DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'default'; 
</script>

Comment: Move the JS file to after the var in the php

Answer (score 0):

this is a workable code , try it. I hope it can help you.

## main html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test Var</title>
  <script src="file_js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <br>
    Value before : <span id="valueBefore"></span><br>
    <br>
    Value after : <span id="valueAfter"></span><br>
    <br>

   <script>

    var DiaLControl_auto_HTML="default value";


    // the function() wil be executed when your page is loaded
    // better use readystate==complete, but it is a another problem...
    window.addEventListener("load",function() {


     // set var  
     DiaLControl_auto_HTML = 'my_value';
     // show it in browser
     document.getElementById('valueBefore').innerHTML=DiaLControl_auto_HTML;

     // call method on file_js 
     myOwnFunction();
     // show it in browser
     document.getElementById('valueAfter').innerHTML=DiaLControl_auto_HTML;

    })
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## file_js.js

```
 // file_js.js FILE
 function myOwnFunction () {
     DiaLControl_auto_HTML="Value changed";
 }
```

Comment: i can't edit in vicidial.php
but i can edit in file_js.js

Comment: what do you mean by "I can't edit" : it's another person who write the php or the main html code ? you have access only to file_js ? post some code you wrote, with console.log("val DiaLControl_auto_HTML="+DiaLControl_auto_HTML) where you can, and copy past console output to show us  the problem.